# How to add close button to customized mat-datepicker-header

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I am using this UI component from the Angular material.

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header

I want to add close button the custom header but it seems not possible yet.

At least I would like to get output event from the date picker header component.

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by you can't add the close button..? The button does not work? Or does the button not show at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `MatDatepicker` and `MatCalendarHeader` are two separate components, you will need to pass data between the components using an `EventEmitter`, or with `BehaviourSubject` through the use of a service.

For this example, I will make use of a service. First, you may create a service called `calendar-service.ts`, which will be used to share data between components. Within this class, we will make use of [BehaviourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) to emit the updated boolean value which will denote if the datepicker should be open or close.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {

  closeCalendarSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isCloseCalander = this.closeCalendarSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  closeCalander(message: boolean) {
    this.closeCalendarSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

On the template for your `MatCalendarHeader`, you should add a button which is binded to the click event, which will trigger the action to close the datepicker

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="closeCalendar()" >
  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

And on the component.ts for the header,

```
constructor(
  private calendarService: CalendarService) {
}

closeCalendar() {
  this.calendarService.closeCalander(true);
}
```

On the main component that uses the `MatDatepicker`, you will subscribe to the observable which will emit the current value from the header component.

```
@ViewChild('picker', { static: false}) picker;
exampleHeader = ExampleHeader;

constructor(private calendarService: CalendarService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.calendarService.isCloseCalander.subscribe(isClose => {
    if (isClose) {
      this.picker.close();
    }
  });
}
```

I have created the full demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtey6n?file=app/datepicker-custom-header-example.ts).

Comment: ok but what if you want multiple instances of said custom MatDatePickerComponent ? They will share data from a same single instance of CalendarService. It is not scoped-safe and can lead to major side effects. Of course your example works for the sake of a tutorial in which you will declare a mat-date-picker only once, but not for production apps with multiple date pickers (for instance a large form with 3 different datepickers for birthday + spouse birthday + subscription date).

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid I think you can solve that by providing the service component level.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775018/seperate-instances-of-an-angular-service-per-set-of-components

Answer (score 3):

I think you should have a look at this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-now-button?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-custom-header-example.ts). You should be able to get it working without the `calendarService`. Basically you can grab a hold of the parent date picker component in the constructor:

```js
constructor(
    private datePicker: MatDatepicker<D>,
    private calendar: MatCalendar<D>,
    private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>,
    @Inject(MAT_DATE_FORMATS) private dateFormats: MatDateFormats,
    cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    this.calendar.stateChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe(() => cdr.markForCheck());
  }
```

I'm using it with a today button in the HTML:

```
<button
    mat-icon-button
    class="todayButton"
    (click)="todayClicked()"
    matTooltip="Select today"
  >
    {{ today }}
  </button>
```

Then the method is called and the `this.datePicker.close()` will close the calendar pop up:

```
todayClicked() {
    this.calendar.activeDate = this.dateAdapter.today();
    this.calendar._dateSelected(this.calendar.activeDate);
    this.datePicker.select(this.dateAdapter.today());
    this.datePicker.close();
  }
```

Courtesy of the original creator: @tabuckner

Comment: only answer that follows the docs - but such a ridiculous solution - +1 anyway its not your fault ;)

Answer (score 1):

Came across this and thought I would share what I found.

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13212), there was a fork added so that you can use the  component as a wrapper and as such, you will be getting all the neat functionality of the  component.

To utilize this, your template is as simple as

```
<mat-calendar-header>
  <button>TODAY</button>
</mat-calendar-header>
```

Here is a link to my stackblitz with the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-today-button?file=src/main.ts